# android.widget.AnalogClock set time

Tags: android, clock, preset

Is there a way to have the android.widget.AnalogClock display a preset time?

I don't want to create a custom AnalogClock, I just want the regular one to display a time to my liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, the `AnalogClock` widget only displays the system time. You might be able to subclass it to have it pull another time, or you can always try cloning the code out of the open source project to create one that accepts a time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project,

https://github.com/anoopelias/Android-Analog-Chronometer

It has an analog ClockView widget as well as a Chronometer. The clock view widget will do exactly the same.

Disclaimer : I am the author of the project.